# Mongoose not working with destructured imports

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, ecmascript-6

I have been working on a simple Express app with ES6. When creating a schema and model for Mongoose, I use this syntax:

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const PostSchema = new Schema(
  {
    userId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    video: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    location: {
        type: { type: String },
        coordinates: []
    }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

PostSchema.index({ location: '2dsphere' });

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
export default Post;
```

It generates this error: `TypeError: _mongoose.Schema is not a constructor`.

When I use this syntax, it works:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const { Schema } = mongoose;
...
```

This is my `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my import style, or my Babel config?
Thanks.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that the import syntax is not destructuring.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose does not support destructuring imports.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html#destructured-imports

> The only import syntax Mongoose supports is `import mongoose from 'mongoose'`. Syntaxes like `import * from 'mongoose'` or `import { model } from 'mongoose'` do **not** work. The global Mongoose object stores types, global options, and other important properties that Mongoose needs. When you do `import { model } from 'mongoose'`, the `this` value in `model()` is not the Mongoose global.

When using TypeScript you should be able to get away with destructuring interfaces and types, but that's about it.